# Defining HibernateExceptionTranslator: No persistence exception translators found in bean factory

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa

I am trying to inject a eventRepository which is Spring Data Repository in my project:

```
public class App {

    protected static EntityManagerFactory factory;

    @Autowired
    protected EventRepository eventRepository;

    public void execute() {
        Event foo = eventRepository.findBySlug("abraxas");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context =
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");

        App runner = (App) context.getBean("AppBean");
        runner.execute();
    }
}
```

beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <bean id="AppBean" class="org.app.App"></bean>
    <jpa:repositories base-package="org.app.repository" />
</beans>
```

But when I run it I get following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No persistence exception translators found in bean factory. Cannot perform exception translation.
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators
```

In some comments I found I need to "configure `HibernateExceptionTranslator`", but I did not manage to find out how.

I am trying to follow the [official documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/) which does not mention configuration of `HibernateExceptionTranslator`.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously the solution was adding

```
     <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateExceptionTranslator"/>
```

to beans.xml

Solution found thanks to [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet).

Answer (score 1):

With Java Config:

```
@Bean
public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator() {
    return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
}
```

Using this import if using Hibernate 3:

```
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateExceptionTranslator;
```

or this one if using Hibernate 4:

```
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateExceptionTranslator;
```

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is `Java.lang.IllegalStateException` which is not subclass of `hibernateException` the how spring's `HibernateExceptionTranslator` can translate your exception to `DataAccessException(Runtime Exception)`.

so instead of `HibernateExceptionTranslator` add `org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor` in your configuration file or `applicationC0ntext-*.xml`. Then mark `@Repository` annotation in persistence file with suitable component scan in `applicationC0ntext-*.xml` or configuration file.